# How to create a Mac bootable gparted or Parted Magic thumb drive?

Tags: usb, disk-utility, unix, bootable-disk

Is it possible to create a Mac-bootable thumb drive containing [gparted](http://gparted.org/) or [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/) without installing a full Linux distribution?

I tried several methods like

- [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net) (some blogs suggest this though the unetbootin site explicitly mentions that it isn't possible)
- `sudo dd if=/.../.iso of=/dev/rdiskx`

which both failed.

Answer (score 4):

The following steps have been tested on macOS Mojave 10.14.6 and I confirm I was able to boot GParted on a 2019 MacBook Air (with secure boot disabled). That being said, the keyboard and trackpad didn’t work as drivers [are not yet available](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/310324/323825) on live distros. Also, the new T2 chip currently prevents live distros from accessing the SSD (another driver issue).

**Step 1:** Open `Disk Utility`.

**Step 2:** Click on `View` (upper left) and select `Show All Devices`.

**Step 3:** Select your thumb drive and click `Erase`.

**Step 4:** Select `MS-DOS (FAT)` as `Format` and `GUID Partition Map` as `Scheme`.

[image: Disk Utility]

**Step 5:** Click `Erase`.

**Step 6:** Download the latest [gparted-live-1.0.0-3-amd64.zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/).

**Step 7:** Double-click on `gparted-live-1.0.0-3-amd64.zip` to unzip folder.

**Step 8:** Copy all files from `gparted-live-1.0.0-3-amd64` to your thumb drive.

You now have a bootable version of GParted that should work on your Mac!

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why the AMD64 version works, I thought Macs used Intel processors. 

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an alternative boot manager such as [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), then either method will work.

Note that you also need to use a USB keyboard and mouse (or built-in on a laptop) for initial installation/use — Bluetooth pairings that work within the EFI boot manager won't persist once you boot Linux.