# How to make and use an USB stick with GParted that will boot on a Mac?

Tags: usb, startup

I want to create a USB stick with GParted on it that will be recognized by my Mac. Obviously, I want to *create* it on a Mac, also. This is not mentioned in the documentation [here](http://gparted.org/liveusb.php).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will answer my own question. Since I had a lot of trouble creating Live USBs on Ubuntu and Mac and wanted to dig a bit deeper into the subject and will also list the output of the successful partition schemes.

- Download .iso from [here](http://gparted.org/download.php) under "stable releases". If unsure, chose the 32bit-Version.
- Put a USB stick in the slot and look into Disk Utility for its device number (disk1, disk2, diskX, etc). This can be found by clicking the icon "Info".
- Open up a shell
- Unmount the stick in terminal (nowhere else) with `sudo diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskX`

**Make sure you don't `dd` to a wrong disk, e.g. your working HDD!**

- Copy the downloaded file with `sudo dd bs=1m if=file.iso of=/dev/rdiskX`

We use the *r* for *raw* in `of=/dev/rdiskX` to make the copy [faster](http://daoyuan.li/solution-dd-too-slow-on-mac-os-x/). You should *not* be using the `s1` extensions: these are partitions on the disk, not the disk itself.

The USB stick then looks like this with `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *7.8 GB     disk1
   1:                       0xEF                         3.0 MB     disk1s2
```

---

`sudo gdisk -l /dev/diskX` will show this (aborting the question is possible with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>):

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid MBR and GPT. Which do you want to use?
 1 - MBR
 2 - GPT
 3 - Create blank GPT
Your answer:
```

---

Finally, `sudo fdisk /dev/diskX` will show

```
Disk: /dev/disk1    geometry: 942/255/63 [15138816 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 2: EF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    535612 -       5948] <Unknown ID>
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

---

OS X will show a dialog to *Initialise...*, *Ignore* or *Unmount* the USB stick when it is put into the slot. Clicking *Ignore* is safe. I put the German screenshot in, I think it's pretty clear.

[image: dialog upon inserting USB stick]

When booting the Mac now press <kbd>alt</kbd> and there should be an option to boot to that is called `EFI boot`. This will bring up GParted Live.

But beware, there are some Macs (e.g. Macbook Pro 17" Early 2011 that are not able at all to boot anything other from USB than OS X).

Comment: Which download should I use for an i7 Mac - I tried the AMD64 but it keeps crashing

Comment: This is good information. Another good tool that I have been using recently to get images onto USB is Etcher: https://etcher.io/

Comment: Thanks, I did it with etcher, took me 1 minute.

Comment: Using dd didn’t work for me. Think it has to do with dd writing a MBR scheme. I believe GUID is required now to boot off USB thumb drives. The following worked for me. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166807/how-to-create-a-mac-bootable-gparted-or-parted-magic-thumb-drive/365283#365283

Comment: I wanted to add that you will need to connect an external USB keyboard/mouse to use the live USB of gParted or CloneZilla on MacBook Pro 2016 or later

I know the post is a bit late, but I was searching for how to do this and this was the best post I found so wanted to note that.

Comment: Your post is not late. I just came back to my own answer to recognise why my Macbook Pro from 2010 will not boot anything from USB...

Answer (score 7):

> Note: This answer does not require any third party tools or the use of the Terminal application.

### How to Create a GParted Bootable Flash Drive

> Note: The operating system used to create the bootable flash drive was macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6.

1. Download the latest [gparted-live-*-amd64.zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/) file. Replace `*` with the current version. For example, if the latest version is `1.3.1-1`, then you want the [gparted-live-1.3.1-1-amd64.zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/1.3.1-1/) file. I assume this file will download to your `Downloads` folder. After the download completes, the zip file will automatically convert to a folder. I my case, this folder was named `gparted-live-1`.
2. Use the Disk Utility application to erase a `500 MB` or larger flash drive. Select the options shown below.

   [image]
3. Using the Finder application, open the folder named `gparted-live-1`. The contents are shown below. Use the Finder application to copy the contents to the flash drive.

   [image]
4. Make the following changes to the names of the boot files, so the firmware in your Mac will boot directly from GRUB. From a Finder window, open the `EFI` folder on the flash drive, then open the `boot` folder. The result should be the folder shown below.

   [image]

   Rename `bootx64.efi` to `bootx64original.efi`. Duplicate `grubx64.efi` to produce `grubx64.efi copy`, then rename `grubx64.efi copy` to `bootx64.efi`. The result should be the folder shown below.

   [image]

### How to Boot from a GParted Flash Drive

A GParted flash drive was tested to successfully boot on the following computers with the latest firmware updates installed.

- iMac (20 inch, Mid 2007)
- iMac (21.5 inch, Mid 2011)
- iMac (21.5 inch, Late 2013)
- Mac mini (2018)

> Note:  I had access to an Apple wireless keyboard and an Apple wireless mouse. Neither worked with GParted. You may need to use a wired keyboard and wired mouse.

Using the above Macs, GParted was found to recognized the internal drives and USB external drives. However, GParted did not recognize an external Thunderbolt 3 SSD.

Steps to boot GParted.

1. Insert the flash drive in a USB port on the Mac.
2. Restart the Mac and immediately hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key.
3. When the Startup Manager icons appears, choose the external drive icon labeled `EFI Boot`.

> Note: When prompted, the default option was chosen.

### References

[GNU/Linux Method B: Manual](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php#linux-method-b)
If you read this reference, you will realize the advantages of using macOS instead of Linux.

Comment: I wanted to add that you will need to connect an external USB keyboard/mouse to use the live USB of gParted or CloneZilla on MacBook Pro 2016 or later

I know the post is a bit late, but I was searching for how to do this and this was the best post I found so wanted to note that.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late, but I was searching how to do this and this was the best post I found.

I wanted to add that [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) is available for OSX now and just by running it with the latest version of [GPARTED](https://gparted.org/download.php) I was able to fix my PCIe SSD in seconds.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It's not clear if you have a new question or need to comment. If you can edit this to include the version number on what "latest" is - it might make a good edit to another post or turn this into an answer that would get votes.