# How to use a 2 TB external hard drive containing existing data as TimeMachine backup storage without losing data already on it?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, partition, filesystem

I have an 2 TB external hard drive. It is formatted as NTFS format, supported by ntfs-3g which is installed using Homebrew. There is already about 500 GB data existing on it that I need to keep. I now want to use the rest of the space on it to store my TimeMachine backups. There is only one partition on the hard drive. I do not have other hard drives to shuffle the data. How can I start to use this hard drive to store my Time Machine backups?

Comment: Would you not just use some third party application such a [GParted](https://gparted.org) to shrink the NTFS partition and add a new JHFS+ partition? To make a bootable GParted see "[How to make and use an USB stick with GParted that will boot on a Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271739/how-to-make-and-use-an-usb-stick-with-gparted-that-will-boot-on-a-mac)".

Comment: Do you have access to another machine that is running Windows?

Comment: I got impatient and burned the data I really need to keep into a DVD. Now I'm ready to just erase everything on the hard drive create two partitions, one NTFS, the other APFS. How to do that?

Comment: @qazwsx Not APFS. Time Machine can only use HFS+.

Comment: I think you are wrong. I just finished saving TimeMachine backup on one of the two new APFS partitions. Now I just need to figure out how to change the other APFS partition to NTFS for storing and sharing other data on macOS and Windows machine. Any tip?

Answer (score 1):

Time Machine can only work on a volume formatted as HFS+. So you will need to repartition this drive. A quick Google shows that it is possible to resize an NTFS partition, but this can't be done with Disk Utility on MacOS.

I wouldn't recommend playing with the partitioning on the volume if the 500Gb of stuff isn't also backed up somewhere else.

Comment: It is NTFS. I added the info in the post.

Comment: I wonder if you can create a sparse disk image on the drive and backup to that? I have done similar things over a network onto a Windows PC but not sure if it will work with a local NTFS drive that has a mounter sparseimage on it...