# Mac Partition Error (Cannot add new Partition / Bootcamp partition not showing / Spaces don't add up to disk)

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, macos

So I am trying to add more space to Bootcamp by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WRkeL1Lnq8&ab_channel=JohnShirley). But the first red flag came when I went into the partition menu: It doesn't show the partition for Bootcamp. Then I saw that the "free space" part and the "Macintosh HD" doesn't add up to 1TB, in fact, it is more, and I 100% know for sure that this iMac model that I bought in 2019 is only 1TB. (shown in image)
[image]

I decided to add a new partition and set it at 200GB and run it, but then it gave me this error (can't copy paste so the image below)
[image]

So I decided to do some googling but didn't see anyone has anything close to this.

I ran `diskutil list` and got this back:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk2⁩         870.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data ⁨BOOTCAMP⁩                130.0 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *28.0 GB    disk1
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk2⁩         27.7 GB    disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +897.7 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Stores disk1s2, disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     546.7 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            14.9 GB    disk2s2
   3:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 14.9 GB    disk2s2s1
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 285.5 MB   disk2s3
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                652.6 MB   disk2s4
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      3.2 GB     disk2s5

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *250.0 GB   disk3
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 ⁨KIMI'S USB⁩              250.0 GB   disk3s1
```

What should I do so that I can partition space from my free space that is in the Macintosh HD drive?

One note is that when I was initially installing Bootcamp, I did force quit bootcamp helper and deleted that partition because it was taking too long, and I reran it afterwards, so that might be the root of the problem

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Does *" I bought in 2019"* mean your Mac is a 2019 model? Might be helpful to know which version of macOS.

Answer (score 1):

The Disk Utility application can often present incorrect information. This seems to be the case with respect to your question. On the other hand, the `diskutil list` command outputs a very reliable information.

You can use the `diskutil` command to create free space after the `Apple_APFS` partition on the internal SATA HDD. The commands given below are based on the output from `diskutil list` command given in your question. You can use the command given below to show how much the `Apple_APFS` partition on the internal SATA HDD could be shrunk.

```
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 limits
```

Provided the space is available, the command below would shrink the `Apple_APFS` partition on the internal SATA HDD to 770 GB and create 100 GB of free space between the `Apple_APFS` partition and the `Microsoft Basic Data` partition.

```
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 770G
```

There are third party tools which can move (or resize upward) a `Microsoft Basic Data` partition which is NTFS formatted. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434419/how-to-add-to-macos-free-space-from-diskutil-list/434444#434444) for a discussion regarding the pros and cons of these tools and the recommendation of first using `chkdsk`.

Apple often uses proprietary SSDs which require special drivers. In your case you have a Fusion Container which uses an internal SSD and internal HDD. Windows also resides on this HDD. Here, I assume the HDD uses a standard SATA interface and therefore can be successfully modified by the third party tools discussed in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434419/how-to-add-to-macos-free-space-from-diskutil-list/434444#434444).