# Keyboard and touchpad are not working when booting from live USB

Tags: keyboard, usb, startup, trackpad, efi

I have a MacBook Pro (mid 2017, 13", no Touch Bar) and I want to create Linux live USB. However, keyboard and trackpad are not working when I'm booting Linux OS from live USB. I'm able to select EFI boot, proceed to selection how I want to boot my Linux system but as soon as OS is loaded - trackpad and keyboard don't respond. I tried Ubuntu 16.04 and Linux Mint 18.03.

Did anyone succeeded to boot Linux OS from a machine similar to mine? How can I create workable Linux (preferably Ubuntu) live USB on my MacBook?

Comment: The keyboard and trackpad are USB devices.  Try an external USB keyboard and see if that works - if it doesn't then Linux isn't loading (or detecting) the USB peripherals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu does not natively support MacBook Pro Mid-2017 yet, so you have to manually install some drivers and patches to get it fully working. During the process, you will need a usb mouse. Also if you don’t have a usb keyboard, you can use on-screen keyboard (which is what I did). Then you have to follow this tutorial: [Linux on MacBook Pro Late 2016 and later](https://gist.github.com/roadrunner2/1289542a748d9a104e7baec6a92f9cd7)

Comment: Is there any Linux distribution available now that would boot on MacBook Pro Mid-2017 without any problems?

Comment: Sorry, but I can’t help you with that.

Comment: @Peter, here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/316972/6533

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Just use a USB mouse and go over to the Bluetooth section under Ubuntu and you will see the mouse appear. You just have to connect it and turn the keyboard on and off via the switch and then press enter several times and you'll see that Bluetooth will find it again. You can then click and connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution to help is to disable the ACPI option (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) by adding acpi=off to the kernel boot options.

Touchpad would work after that but since ACPI is used for hardware acceleration you will probably experience some higher CPU usage.