# Need an external Linux with hardware driver and support for MacBook Pro 2016 or newer

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, unix

What Linux support hardware drivers for screen / trackpad and optionally all keys?

Core requirements:

1. no state changes to the original hard disk (this qualifies it as "external" )
2. drivers for Apple screen resolution and GPU if possible
3. Apple keyboard drivers or support
4. Drivers for the trackpad OR a usb mouse
5. Network is minimal - ethernet OR wifi

Optional requirements (the more that work the better):

1. the full function key row drivers)
2. audio drivers
3. all external mouse
4. all external keyboard
5. all external screen
6. all external audio
7. Run on bare metal - I'm open to a virtual solution if that's the only thing that can work, but I'd rather have linux boot against the actual hardware so I have one OS running on the Mac hardware.

Now -

---

<sub>• Knoppix (7.7.1 DVD EN) gives a dead screen.
• Ubuntu (16.04.4 LTS) fails at keyboard. (A website says to run "a bunch of commands" to enable it, but it's an unjustifiable risk due to fidelity needs of the original hard disk.) Besides, [further evidence](https://askubuntu.com/q/1011090/344328) shows that (unlike Puppy Linux) Ubuntu has no respect for user data hence I wouldn't be surprised if it touches the original hard disk and go all "*you should have already read the legal disclaimer I probably hadn't written*".</sub>

Comment: I'm going to edit pretty hard and then reopen. The requirements are very detailed which should make this able to get answers. I get the general guidance to not ask "off site resource" but this might be clear enough to be useful. Let's see. Also - we can discuss on [meta] if anyone has close or open heartburn.

Comment: See https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux and https://gist.github.com/roadrunner2/1289542a748d9a104e7baec6a92f9cd. Using VirtualBox might be easier...

Comment: Now I‘m confused. In the „evidence“ link (which actually doesn‘t explain why you think a live Ubuntu touches the hard drive) you mention that you got Ubuntu running from a pendrive on your Mac. So what exactly is the question you are asking here now?

Comment: Currently working gist link: https://gist.github.com/roadrunner2/1289542a748d9a104e7baec6a92f9cd7